# Scala groupBy and mapValue

Tags: scala

Supposing I have a list of tuples:

```
val temp = List((string1, int1), (string2, int2), (string1, int3))
```

and I wanted it to groupBy to become a Map of the following format, how could I do it?

```
Map(string1 -> List(int1, int3), string2 -> List(int2))
```

If I use groupBy directly, it will result in something like this:

```
temp.groupBy(x => x._1)

// output
Map(string1 -> List((string1,int1),(string1,int3)), string2 -> List((string2,int2)))
```

I understand that mapValue might be useful in this case, but I couldn't wrap my head around this.

Comment: `(string3, int3)` in the first line should be `(string1, int3)` right?

Comment: `temp.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)` is enough.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I've made the edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the first groupBy you have in the `string1` case this list: `List((string1,1), (string1,3))`

You can map it to only keep the second value with `.map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))}`

### Working example

```scala
val temp = List(("string1", 1), ("string2", 2), ("string1", 3))

println(temp.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k,v) => (k,v.map(_._2))})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well! What will be the time complexity for such an approach?